# Creating Linq Expression to convert int to enum name in AutoMapper projection

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-6, automapper, linq-expressions

I'd like to streamline my current view model mapping. I currently use Automapper `ProjectTo` to create my view model, then call a post mapping method to populate a `StatusDescription` `string` property from a `Status` enum whose value is in another `int` property in the view model class, `StatusId`.

I found [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333034/how-to-map-an-int-to-its-enum-description-using-automapper-during-a-queryable-pr), but I am not able to get it to work, and am having a hard time understanding what exactly it is doing due to my general lack of experience with expressions.

For reference, here is the expression method (note I had to comment out the defaultValue parameter as I was getting an error `An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments`:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, String>> CreateEnumToStringExpression<TSource, TMember>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> memberAccess)//,string defaultValue = ""
{
    string defaultValue = "";
    var type = typeof(TMember);
    if (!type.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("TMember must be an Enum type");
    }

    var enumNames = Enum.GetNames(type);
    var enumValues = (TMember[])Enum.GetValues(type);

    var inner = (Expression)Expression.Constant(defaultValue);

    var parameter = memberAccess.Parameters[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < enumValues.Length; i++)
    {
        inner = Expression.Condition(
        Expression.Equal(memberAccess.Body, Expression.Constant(enumValues[i])),
        Expression.Constant(enumNames[i]),
        inner);
    }

    var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, string>>(inner, parameter);

    return expression;
}
```

I am calling it like this:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Status, option =>
    option.MapFrom(src =>
        EnumHelper.ExpressionHelper
        .CreateEnumToStringExpression((ShippingContainerHeader s) => s.StatusId)
    ))
```

The error I am getting when I run this is: 
`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression..`

A.) I think I am calling this wrong maybe? Shouldn't I be using the reference to `src` in the `MapFrom` method call in order to pass the actual value of `StatusId` to the expression method?

B.) Seems like there is an issue with the expression generation method as it is producing the `ToString()` error. There is not an explicit `.ToString()` call in that method, but it must be implied somehow.

C.) Understanding the code: I can follow all of the code within the `CreateEnumToStringExpression` method except what the `parameter` variable is and the final `expression` variable expression statement. Also the generic types I'm confused on...there are a lot of generic types and the call to the method from the linked example doesn't explicitly define any of them.

In `Expression<Func<TSource, String>>` I'm pretty sure `TSource` is the input, which is an `int`. `String` is the output, which would be the enum name.

In `CreateEnumToStringExpression<TSource, TMember>` and `Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> memberAccess`: `TSource` again is `int`, `TMember` is the enum class type.

But do you not have to explicitly call these out when calling the method? Something like: `CreateEnumToStringExpression<int, StatusesEnum>(new Expression<Func<int, ShippingContainerHeader>> { s => s.StatusId })`

Comment: This isn't merely a cast?

Comment: In any case, the error message is speaking absolute truth.    LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, I just changed the expression to remove the `src =>` like in the linked to answer. That assignment was calling a `ToString()`. Now I get `ShippingContainerHeader` is not an enum, so I changed it to `StatusesEnum`, but now the `=> s.StatusId` is no longer valid...as `s` is referring to the enum type, not the source data type. Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey a simple cast does not work either...it also gives the `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression..` error.

Comment: All providers I've used recognized methods in the `Convert` class. Try using `Convert.ToString()`.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html). That will show where that ToString is coming from. `Object.ToString` might make sense. But `String.ToString`?